# Chemical compound numbering in pdfLaTeX without `--shell-escape`?

Tags: packages, shell-escape, psfrag, chemstyle

The package `chemscheme`, included in `chemstyle`, allows for temporary text "tags" in .eps files to be replaced with designated chemical compound enumerations (A, B, C, ...; 1, 2, 3, ... ; etc.). This relies on the `psfrag` package, which requires DVI output; thus, pdfTeX is not directly compatible. The documentation for chemstyle suggests using `\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}`, which uses `--shell-escape` to convert the relabelled .eps figure to .pdf files. However, arXiv does not allow `--shell-escape`.

Is there a package alternative to `chemscheme` or a workaround that allows similar functionality in pdfTeX? Can .eps figure chemical compound relabelling be done without `--shell-escape`?

Comment: There is `chemnum` but it also uses `psfrag` so the actual replacement works the same way.

Comment: Unfortunately, `chemnum` uses the same mechanism to replace the image. I would like to think that there is way to implement compound labeling without `--shell-escape` (I've clarified the question), especially since the arXiv, to which many chemistry paper preprints are sent, does not allow `--shell-escape`

Comment: @Anthony OT here, but I'd question 'many' chemistry papers going to arXiv. Most chemistry publishers would view that as 'previous publication' and would not take such drafts. (My day job is as a chemistry lecturer)

Comment: One might imagine writing a search-replace routine for EPS files in TeX itself, which would allow renumbering 'in place' (though would be risky as any EPS containing binary data would be messed up). However, I don't think anyone has done that. You've then got the issue that this won't work with PDF-based graphics anyway (fitting in a search-replace with `epstopdf` sounds very tricky). I'm not sure there's an answer here beyond 'no' at present.

Comment: My mistake regarding the arXiv and chemistry. Many of the professors at my university with whom I am familiar send preprints to the arXiv, though perhaps I am overgeneralizing, given these are mostly physical chemists. (I am only an undergraduate.) Do you normally just use the default latex (non-pdf) for chemistry publications when you need chemical compound labeling? Also, would you like to include your "no" response as an answer, so I may close the question?

Comment: @JosephWright You have mail ^^.

Comment: @cfr JosephWright actually ended up answering my questions over chat: he said that chemistry publications normally would expect Word documents and that he only uses LaTeX for reports and such. Furthermore, he usually includes finalized images, rather than images in which the temporary compound labels would need to be replaced.